# Change url to nix.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, status-declined, site-name

The point is that this portal tries to answer all questions related to Unix as well as Linux. For that reason, the url of U&L should be `nix.stackexchange.com`. Can this be changed?

**EDIT:**
The /status-declined and the comment and the answer only denote ignorance to me, by first treating Linux same as Unix, while they are not, and then just using Unix generically for Unix as well as Linux instead of separating both or merging them equally. I won't even start on the differences between the two over here. They are just 2 different pieces of software. The only reason they are usually mentioned together is because of the similarities between Unix and Linux based distros. But that does not make any one of them superior to the other. You cannot say "Unix" and mean "Unix and Linux", no sir.

Comment: As Gilles [answered](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/1360/21281), the change would muddy the waters and not clarify them.  As a regular user of both Linux and various brands of Unix, I wouldn't know to look for something called "nix".

Comment: nix is also, in many English speaking countries, slang for "nothing" (from the German, *nichts*)...

Answer (score 9):

Why change the URL to “nix”? It means the same thing as “unix”, only it's less clear.

Your reason is not obvious at all. I assume it's to avoid the name “unix”. [We don't officially endorse or discourage the use of “'nix” or “un*x”](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/euphemisms-for-unix/470#470). Changing the URL to “nix” might hurt our searchability though.

“Unix” already includes Linux. We [include “Linux” in the site name](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/how-about-a-rename) because a majority of visitors are after Linux and not Unix. Both https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/ reach this site.